# Quicktime Screen Recording Lower Frame Rate

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

I'm on mac, I'd like to screen record. But I want it to record a frame every second or so, or every minute or so (as opposed to 30fps). So when someone plays the video it will look sped up.

Is there a way to do this in quicktime (preferably) and if not, is there an app or a command line tool I can use to adjust the framerate after recording?

Comment: Why don't you just record the video at 30 FPS then modify the video to increase its playback after the fact?

Comment: @Ramhound If you had read to the end of his question, you would have realized he had thought of that and was asking for help on that aspect as well.

Comment: I actually did read the question.  I took his question as wanting to modify the recording, so it would record at 1 FPS, instead of 30 FPS.

Comment: Also another problem with recording the video at 30fps or whatever it records is that after 30 minutes it already takes 1gb. :/ If it were lower framerate it wouldn't take as much.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Although it doesn't use Quicktime it seems to be a good way to do it.

Just take an image every X seconds, and then after you have hundreds (or thousands) of images combine them into a movie.

An example that does this:
https://github.com/potomak/screencapture

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this directly in Quicktime as of this writing without writing a relatively complicated Applescript.

The laan (hi Jason!) post above seems to be gone. I humbly offer our app that does most of what you want for free. It also lets you choose specific apps (as well as your whole screen) and you can deselect apps later if you don't want them in the final export 
[Motif time lapse screen capture](http://screenmotif.com)